# Unparsed aapt error(s)!

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt

I'm working with Android in Eclipse and was trying to combine code from a template project I found into the skeleton project that Android creates when you start a new project.  This is not an initial setup; have gotten several projects running and although I'm new to Android coding I have been working for several weeks without this problem  so the environment is set up fine I think.

The error I'm seeing is -

```
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output
```

At one point I cleared the console messages and now even after closing the project and Eclipse, then reopening I get no console messages and none of my source or resource files are flagged.

What is aapt and where should I look for the source of this error?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try here: http://www.anddev.org/sdk-adt-emulator-problems-f16/unparsed-aapt-errors-check-the-console-for-output-t12615.html

Comment: Found that by simply deleting the error on the 'Problem' window (right click | delete) will remove error.  Then re-run the app and the Console will once again display the issues that need to be tracked down.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I sorted this out. So for anyone else still on the learning curve with me, the solultion is as noted in my comment. In addition -

aapt = Android Asset Packaging Tool
[From the Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/index.html#detailed-build) - 
"The Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) takes your application resource files, such as the AndroidManifest.xml file and the XML files for your Activities, and compiles them."

The solution for me was simply to delete the error on the 'Problem' window (right click | delete). Then, force a rebuild by rerunning the app. Any remaining problems will now show up and be logged so you can track them down.

Hope this is helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

This happened for me when I accidentally attempted to "run" an Android XML layout file.  It created a file with the layout name and `_out.xml` appended.  I needed to delete that file before I could perform any further builds.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did using Eclipse ADT, and that error disappeared:

Window > Preferences > Android > DDMS > Base local debugger port: 8600

I changed the value from 8600 to something else, example: 9999

Finally, I went to Project > Clean... > Clean all projects > OK

The error disappeared.

Answer (score -2):

May occur when the project is created (New Android) and Fields: minimum required SDK, Target SDK, compile with and Theme are not filled in correctly.